# Extract a value after a character and unknown amount of non-digit characters

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

From the below data, what I need from the RegEx is to extract the value amounts as shown in bold below.  I was using https://regex101.com/ to test expressions for a value but couldn't get it quite right, what RegEx can achieve this?  I am trying to extract the value after the % symbol.

```
%\d?.*
```

The above matches everything after the % but I am only looking for the value.

Test 1 46.6500% $ **4,463.82**

Test 2 36.5000% **25,215.72**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew will add some code to show starting point and difficulty, I've looked around StackOverflow for a little but found no solutions, I will keep looking elsewhere and answer my own question later, thank you.

Comment: Does this work for you? `[^%]*$`

Comment: @Antsushi no, it's taking all characters after %, i need to only extract the first digit and after

Comment: Try `%\D*(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)$`, see https://regex101.com/r/fRM7Gw/1, grab Group 1 value. Note you do not need any lookarounds, unless you explain what the reason is behind this requirement.

Comment: @William Humphries Then maybe this? `[^% ]*$` this assumes that you are always going to have a space after % and don't have any spaces in the strings you want to extract.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? As the [regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew .NET, thank you, both solutions provide grab the value at the end of the string.  Thank you for explaining lookarounds.

Comment: So, in C#,  you may use `Regex.Match(str, @"%\D*(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)$")?.Groups[1].Value` or `Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=%\D*)\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?$")?.Value`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you Wiktor, got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use two approaches:

- Use a capturing group and once a match is found, get Group 1 value
- If the regex engine supports variable-width lookbehind patterns, use this to set the left-hand context pattern that won't get "consumed", won't be added to the match value, but matching the pattern is required.

The first approach can be implemented with

```
%\D*(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)$
    ^-- cap. group --^
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%25%5cD*%28%5cd%28%3f%3a%5b.%2c%5cd%5d*%5cd%29%3f%29%5cr%3f%24&i=Test+1+46.6500%25+%24+4%2c463.82%0d%0aTest+2+36.5000%25+25%2c215.72&o=m).

The second approach (lookbehind-based) regex is

```
(?<=%\D*)\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?$
^-  LB -^
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%25%5cD*%29%5cd%28%3f%3a%5b.%2c%5cd%5d*%5cd%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=Test+1+46.6500%25+%24+4%2c463.82%0d%0aTest+2+36.5000%25+25%2c215.72&o=m).

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=%\D*)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a `%` followed with 0+ non-digit chars immediately to the left of the current location
- `%` - a `%` char
- `\D*` - 0 or more non-digit chars
- `(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)` - Group 1:

  - `\d` - a digit
  - `(?:[.,\d]*\d)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches one or zero occurrences of:

    - `[.,\d]*` - 0 or more occurrences of `.`, `,` or digit
    - `\d` - a digit
- `$` - end of string.

Since you use .NET, here are the C# code snippets showing how to extract the first occurrence with both approaches:

```
var result1 = Regex.Match(str, @"%\D*(\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?)$")?.Groups[1].Value;
var result2 = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=%\D*)\d(?:[.,\d]*\d)?$")?.Value;
```